# When clicking buttons change mouse position unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

> I am trying to build a mobile game with a feature where we can navigate the screen with Mouseposition.

I also have buttons in the canvas.

When I am pressing a button the screen rotates to the button position.

If there is any other ways to navigate with screen please help me.

Or if somebody knows how to implement this with touch system please help.
My code.

```
void Start(){
   initialrot = transform.rotation;
  }


void Update(){
      float x = 
  Input.GetAxis("Mouse x");
       float y = 
    Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");


    Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(x,y,0);

 transform.eulerangles = initialrot  * mousePos;
     }
```

Comment: You know that scripts in Unity are programmed in C# and not C++?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Mistake